# How do I setup git to push and pull from the current branch?

Tags: git, git-push, git-pull

So I have two tracked branches in my repo, 'testing' and 'master'. These are tracking to the same named branches on my remote server. I have the .gitconfig option for push.default set to 'tracking'. However when I do "git push origin" it merges my new changes with the Master branch ont he remote server. Here is the output of 'git remote show origin':

```
* remote origin
Fetch URL: git+ssh://******************
Push  URL: git+ssh://******************
HEAD branch: master
Remote branches:
  master  tracked
  testing tracked
Local refs configured for 'git push':
  master  pushes to master  (up to date)
  testing pushes to testing (fast-forwardable)`
```

Basically, I want to be able to just type 'git push' and 'git pull' and it will automatically push and pull to origin with the appropriate branch.

EDIT:

```
[*****]$ git config push.default
tracking
[*****]$ git --version
git version 1.7.3.4
```

Comment: Push can not merge. Its impossible, so edit your question to clarify what you mean.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you're saying that both branches are pushed to the matching branches on the remote when you do `git push origin`.  This sounds very surprising to me, if you really have `push.default` correctly set to `tracking`.  Could you also let us know (a) what version of git you're using and (b) that the output of the command `git config push.default` is definitely `tracking`?

Answer (score 1):

You can change this behavior by editing the "push.default" property.

I always use the "simple" mode which tries to find a remote branch having the same name as your current branch and push to it.

```
git config --global push.default simple
```

This is the mode advised for beginners due to his ease of use and safety.

> ...refuse to push if the upstream branch’s name is different from the
>   local one.

Find more in the official doc (end of the page): http://git-scm.com/docs/git-config

Comment: just realized how old this post was :)

Answer (score 0):

```
git config remote.origin.push HEAD
```

See the documentation for [`git push`](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-push.html) (this was in towards the bottom in the examples section).

Comment: Then what does setting push.default to tracking do?